# select rows with multiple conditions on each column

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a problem like the following to be implemented in java.

```
item    view        Hit         Quality(%)
1   20      6       55
2   18      8       67
3   16      7       70
4   13      9       80
5   17      8       85
..  ..      ..      ..
```

I have data here in the above format.

I have to select only those rows whose sum of view, sum of Hit and average value of quality are highest.

This is first problem above and second one is additional like we have minimum limit mentioned for total of view, total of hit and average of total quality like view=100,hit=30 and quality=70%. Here the primary factor is view, secondary factor is hit and third factor is quality. So now again we have to select the rows for these highest values but be careful that sum of view and hit should not be less than limit. If no case to reach at limit, then we can go ahead without caring about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to sort your results:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;


public class Item {
    private int view;
    private int hit;
    private double quality;
    public int getView() {
        return view;
    }
    public void setView(int view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
    public int getHit() {
        return hit;
    }
    public void setHit(int hit) {
        this.hit = hit;
    }
    public double getQuality() {
        return quality;
    }
    public void setQuality(double quality) {
        this.quality = quality;
    }


}


class ExecuteTest{
    public void sort(List<Item> itemList){
      Collections.sort(itemList, new Comparator<Item>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Item item1, Item item2) {
                boolean checkView = true, checkHit = true;
                if(item1.getView() == item2.getView()){
                    checkView = false;
                }
                if(item1.getHit() == item2.getHit()){
                    checkHit = false;
                }

                 if(item1.getView() <=100 &&  item1.getHit() <= 30 && item1.getQuality() <= 70
                         &&
                         item2.getView() <=100 &&  item2.getHit() <= 30 && item2.getQuality() <= 70
                         ){
                     if(checkView && item1.getView() > item2.getView()){
                         return 1;
                     }else if(checkView && item1.getView() < item2.getView()){
                         return -1;
                     }
                     else if(checkHit && item1.getHit() > item2.getHit()){
                         return 1;
                     }else if(checkHit && item1.getHit() < item2.getHit()){
                         return -1;
                     } else if(item1.getQuality() > item2.getQuality()){
                         return 1;
                     } else if(item1.getQuality() < item2.getQuality()){
                         return -1 ;
                     } else{
                         return 0;
                     }


                 }
                return 0;
            }
        });

    }

}
```